# Riak is creating siblings of expired keys in bitcask bucket types

Tags: riak

I have a Riak server using `multi` backend storage with the following configuration:

```
...
storage_backend = multi
multi_backend.bitcask_mult.storage_backend = bitcask
multi_backend.bitcask_mult.bitcask.expiry = 10s
...
```

I have checked that the following sequence of steps works correctly.

1. Put a new value with key `key-1`.
2. Get the value with key `key-1` returns the expected value.
3. Wait 15 seconds.
4. Try to get the value with `key-1`. This returns nothing, as the key has expired.

So far so good.

However, if now I put the value with the same key again...

5. Put a new value with key `key-1`
6. Get the value with `key-1` returns two siblings!

I have waited for hours between steps #4 and #5 (just in case the expiration had to be flushed or something like that), with no luck.

I can address this situation handling the siblings, which is something that I do anyway for some other buckets I work with, but I wasn't expecting to have to deal with "expired siblings"!

I have read something about [automatic expiration and Riak Search](http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.2.0/setup/planning/backend/bitcask/#automatic-expiration-and-riak-search) but I don't think this is the case.

Am I doing something wrong? Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Void, expiration is working but you are running into a problem I will call "Expiration <> Delete". When an object expires in Bitcask a tombstone is created by Bitcask and the backend returns `not_found` to any requests for that object **BUT** the object isn't deleted. The object gets "deleted" when the oldest object in the Bitcask data file expires and the whole file is expired. At that point a new file is created.

Until a new file is created in Bitcask the object actually still exists even though Bitcask is returning `not_found`. When you write to "deleted" key the Bitcask the last-modified time is getting updated essentially resurrecting it.

To test this theory you can actually stop Riak and restart it. Restarting Riak will cause Bitcask to create a new data file and will keep you from getting siblings.

Long story short you still need to deal with siblings in this case.

Comment: I don't think this is quite accurate.  From my reading of the source code, the bitcask backend handles expiry while the riak_kv_vnode layer above it would decide whether or not there is a sibling.  Riak_kv_vnode calls bitcask:get to find any pre-existing value, and bitcask should return notfound if it has already expired.  If I have misready something, please do point it out.